# How to deploy and overwrite only one artifact in artifactory

Tags: java, maven, deployment, artifactory

I have a problem with deploying artifacts into artifactory with just one version for now.

Currently, if I deploy my artifact via `mvn deploy`, always a new version is generated in artifactory e.g.

```
Commons-0.0.1-20131122.222911-4
Commons-0.0.1-20131122.232912-5
Commons-0.0.1-20131122.242913-6
```

How is it possible to only deploy ONE version (overwrite existing artifacts) e.g. Common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or a kind of this into artifactory via `maven`?

For now I have only a `<distributionManagement>` section in my `pom.xml` and `ID` definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can change this in Artifactory repository settings. There is a setting `Maven Snapshot Version Behavior`. If it is set to unique, it will not overwrite artifacts until the limit of `Max Unique Snapshots` is reached. You can change that limit to 1 or set the behavior to Nonunique.

See the documentation [here](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories).

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding Nonunique snapshots, and put a number a bit larger than 1. 3 is a good choice - it will keep the repository small (the oridingal intend of @marcel-holl) and will keep couple of previous versions in case he needs them.